# Plotting Weibull distribution on Wind Speed

Tags: statistics, plotting, matplotlib, distribution

I have a 720 hourly set of wind speed and wind direction data and I want to fit the Weibull Distribution on it. After searching for some time, I wrote the following code in Python to get my distribution, I will also share my image for clarification. [image: windspeed weibull<code>enter code here</code>]

```py
ws.hist(bins=np.arange(0, ws.max()), alpha=0.5, normed=True)
weibull_params = (sc.stats.exponweib.fit(ws,floc=0,f0=1))
x= ws
def weib(x,lamb,k):
   return (k / lamb) * (x / lamb)**(k-1) * np.exp(-(x/lamb)**k)
k_shape, lamb_scale = weibull_params[1], weibull_params[3]

plt.plot(x, weib(x, lamb_scale, k_shape), label='self-defined Weibull')
```

Does this seem alright? How do I make sense of this? I also found a package here but I don't understand how to implement it to my code. https://github.com/cqcn1991/Wind-Speed-Analysis

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps the data points are not in sequential order along the x-axis with is leading to a jump around of the line.

Comment: It is actually a time series data. I used a histogram. Should I sort and then fit it?

Comment: I would check the order of the points in `x` along the x-axis as a first step.  If they are not in sequential order along the x-axis then I would sort `x` and replot to see if it makes a difference.  I suspect that it may.

Comment: It stays the same actually. Maybe because I have too many bins.

Answer (score 2):

Tried a few things in the OP comments that didn't work.  However, you may apply [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) to your project. There is a free [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/) for developers and with the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) you can use these functions in Python.

```
import datetime

from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr
```

Start the Wolfram session

```
wolfSession = WolframLanguageSession()
```

I will collect my own [`WindSpeedData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindSpeedData.html) from a [`WeatherData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeatherData.html) weather station closest to the [`"Country"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/Country.html) [`Entity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html) of Bermuda during October 2016.

```
weatherStation = wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.WeatherData(wl.Entity('Country','Bermuda'))
);
print(weatherStation)
```

> ```
> Entity['WeatherStation', 'TXKF']
> ```

```
windData = wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.WindSpeedData(
        weatherStation,
        [
            datetime.datetime(2016,10,1),
            datetime.datetime(2016,10,31)
        ]
    )
)
```

`windData` is a [`TimeSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) object with observation count comparable to your problem.

```
print(wolfSession.evaluate(windData('PathLength')))
```

> ```
> 1058
> ```

The result can be visualised with [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html) by [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)ing in one of the supported [Raster Image Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RasterImageFormats.html) or [Vector Graphics Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VectorGraphicsFormats.html).

```
wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Export(
        '<path with image filename>', 
        wl.DateListPlot(windData, 
            PlotTheme='Detailed', 
            PlotRange=wl.All, 
            FrameLabel=wl.Automatic
        )
    )
)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

A hurricane passed over in that month with is the cause of that spike in wind speed.

Now that there is data [`Histogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) on the PDF scale gives.

```
hist=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Histogram(windData, wl.Automatic, 'PDF',
        PlotTheme='Detailed', 
        ChartStyle=wl.ColorData('Crayola','Silver'),
        PlotRange=wl.All
    )
);

wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Export(
        '<path with image filename>', 
        hist
    )
)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Use [`EstimatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html) for the [`WeibullDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeibullDistribution.html).

```
windDistrbution=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.EstimatedDistribution(
        wl.QuantityMagnitude(windData('Values')),
        wl.WeibullDistribution(wl.Global.alpha, wl.Global.beta, wl.Global.mu)
    )
);
print(windDistrbution)
```

> ```
> WeibullDistribution[1.883495945177254, 28.34295076324276, -0.7675654467340361]
> ```

Or use [`FindDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html) restricted to the continuous distribution functions to auto find and fit a distribution.

```
autoDistribution=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.FindDistribution(
        wl.QuantityMagnitude(windData('Values')),
        TargetFunctions='Continuous'
    )
);

print(autoDistribution)
```

> ```
> ExtremeValueDistribution[18.436141153779957, 10.204118744677338]
> ```

Check for goodness of with [`DistributionFitTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html).

```
print(
    wolfSession.evaluate(
        wl.Map(
            wl.Function(wl.DistributionFitTest(windData,wl.Slot(1),'PValue')), 
            [windDistrbution,autoDistribution]
        )
    )
)
```

> ```
> [0.0002862317707539308, 0.1802410209978217]
> ```

The Weibull fit is not very good and Extreme Value not that strong.  In any case the [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) the [`PDF`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) functions.

```
pdfs=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Map(
        wl.Function(wl.PDF(wl.Slot(1), wl.Global.x)), 
        [windDistrbution,autoDistribution]
    )
);


pdfPlot=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Plot(
        pdfs,
        [wl.Global.x, 0, wl.QuantityMagnitude(wl.Max(windData))],
        PlotTheme='Detailed',
        PlotLegends=wl.Placed(
            wl.LineLegend(wl.Automatic, [windDistrbution,autoDistribution]), 
            wl.Below)
    )
)

wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Export(
        '<path with image filename>', 
        pdfPlot
    )
)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Combine the plots with [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html).

```
wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.Export(
        '<path with image filename>', 
        wl.Show(hist, pdfPlot)
    )
)
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Terminate the session

```
wolfSession.terminate()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, didn‘t know that you can use Mathematica on Python... need to have a good look!

Comment: @Peter Its new since version 11.3.  They are calling it "Wolfram Language"  these days.  It seems that Mathematica is slowing being rebranded as "Wolfram Desktop".

Comment: Thanks, good to know. I worked with Mathematica some 7 years ago. I really liked it. Looking forward to try Wolfram Language!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try what you suggested. I have meanwhile attempted to fit a distribution to my dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try what you suggested. I have meanwhile attempted to fit a distribution to my dataset. I actually get the following error `wolframclient.exception.WolframKernelException: Cannot locate a kernel automatically. Please provide an explicit kernel path.`

Comment: @ChayanRoychoudhuryBanerjee Download the engine from the link [Wolfram Engine link](http://www.wolfram.com/developer/) in the post.